# optimizing loops in arc610d

Tags: c++, optimization, real-time

I'm working on arc610d, and trying to optimize a loop, for simplification i have written the next code, (when in the real program, cnt1++ will be exchanged with a matrix calculation, for example matrix[h][x] = 1024 - (matrix[h][x]>>2)):

```
register int cnt1;
for(int h = 0; h < 38; h++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 56; x++)
    {
      cnt1++;
    }
}
```

this takes 12779 clock ticks, when plus operation is one clock,
so we have 2 plus operations, and an if,
2 plus operations = 2*2128 = 4248 ticks
this leaves 8531 ticks for the if operation and other loop operations.

does anybody have any suggestions on how to improve performance of this loop,

maybe with a prgma , if manipulations, assembly code, or other suggetions.

Thanks.

Comment: replacing 2 loops to one loop do'esnt help

Comment: Using your compiler's optimizer?  It should improve this code a lot.

Comment: yes, using the compiler optimizer.